# InnoSetup, launch silently a 3rd party InnoSetup installer

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, ffdshow

Wath I'm trying to do is launch silently a 3rd party InnoSetup installer from my own installer.

This is the 3rd party installer: http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/download.php

The parameters that I use works ok If I launch the 3rd party installer form commandline, but If I launch it from my own Installer it shows the language messagebox of the 3rd party installer, is not silent.

Why?, how to fix it?

```
[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\{#InstallerName}.exe; Parameters: "/LANG=en /DIR=""{app}"" /SILENT /NOCANCEL /NORESTART /NOICONS /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES " ; Statusmsg: Installing {#AppName}...; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

Comment: The lang Id. is ok, as I said the same parameters (and in the same order) works from the commandline, thanks anyways for comment

Comment: Have you checked the log to see what command is called in real? Maybe you miss e.g. `WorkingDir: "{tmp}"` or there is different issue?

Comment: I've found the problem, seems that parametizing an InnoSetup installer is very sensitive and I can't put an empty space at the end of the args in my Innosetup Script, this does not happens with an MSI installer and never happened in my life with any other [Run] section from thousands of installers that I've created, I always separate the process args with an empty whitespace at the end, but in this specific case seems to be not possible calling an InnoSetup installer, maybe a bug?, so just removing the empty space in `.../SUPPRESSMSGBOXES " ; Statusmsg...` worked ok.